# How to programmatically send data to arduino from bash

Tags: bash, serial-port, arduino, raspberry-pi

i like to send some data through the serial from my Raspberry Pi to the arduino. My problem is sending it, i read something like `sudo echo "8933" > /dev/ttyUSB0` but it is not working. Sending though the Serial Monitor in the Arduino-IDE works fine and `sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB0` too.
How can i do that programmatically? 
It would be nice if it were a bash-script because i want to run it via ssh.

Comment: I was incorrect above, you should refer here [previous question][1]


  [1]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89182/how-do-you-use-minicom-with-stdin-and-stdout

Comment: @sam pySerial works fine, as far as typing manually. Can you explain how to do that programmatically? Otherwise the method using termios just returns errors that it coudn't open the file... You see I am very new to Python, can you (or someone else) write that to a short py-script?

Comment: Well, what data are you trying to send? i.e. is this data being read from a text file? or is it the output os some script you've written? We need more to go on. You can go about this task any number of ways.

Comment: @sam i get the number (my data) from a sh-script (which reads it using curl from the web) and want send that number to the arduino.

Comment: Take a look at my revised answer. Its not a great long-term solution, but it will get you going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have some script generating data you'd like to send to your Arduino serial monitor you could try a simple python wrapper to send your data.  Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
import sys
import serial

def main():
    data = sys.argv

    if data[1:]:
        ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 19200, timeout=1)
        for d in data[1:]:
            print d
            ser.write(str(d))                            
        ser.close()

    else:
        print "No Input given!\n"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This script will take whatever is passed in as an argument, and send it over serial (i.e. to your Arduino serial monitor).

```
./[this_script] `[your_script]`
```

This is just something I just whipped together, it should probably be cleaned up. I'd consider getting familiar with Python as its perfectly suited for one-off scriptable tasks such as this.

Comment: Running this gives me following error:

$ `python serial_write.py 6334`
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serial_write.py", line 18, in <module>
    main()
  File "serial_write.py", line 11, in main
    ser.write(data)                            
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 471, in write
    n = os.write(self.fd, d)
TypeError: must be string or buffer, not list`

Comment: Sorry, I dont have anything to test this on. It looks like `data` must be cast to a string. Try the corrected version shown above.

Comment: that also does not work, but now there is no output, the script is working so far. Thank you for that. I think there is something wrong with Serial module in python

Comment: this new edit will print out what its trying to send to help you make sense of it.

Comment: I saw, that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24611941/4346956) has no `port.close()` so i tried it without `ser.close()` and now it works fine. thx

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, but on the raspberry it won't work; on my ubuntu PC it does  :/

Comment: It could be a few things. I guessed at `/dev/ttyUSB0`, make sure that matches your desired device. Also make sure pyserial is installed.

Comment: Just found out (after reducing `miniterm` from ~700 to 250 lines) that it only worked if there was `console.getKey()` That is really odd so i came to the conclusion that i may need a delay. Some testing showed me that it has to be in my case minimum 1.5 seconds. I think for most people the delay is not necessary, but in my case it is. I hope that helps someone

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with `sudo echo "8933" > /dev/ttyUSB0`.

1. `echo` appends a newline to whatever it outputs. Try
    `printf "8933"` instead.
2. The `sudo` command only applies to the actual echo. The output file is still opened by "you" (not root) before `sudo` runs. Try `printf "8933" | sudo tee /dev/ttyUSB0 > /dev/null`.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work. My arduino dies not show an incorrect input, it just "reboots" without any serial-transfered-data