# How to time stamp data received via XBee on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, shell, raspberry-pi, xbee

I have a FRDM k64F, which is sending magnetometer data to the Raspberry Pi. Both the devices are connected via a XBEE. I wanted to know how I can time stamp the data that is being sent to the Raspberry Pi and put it into a separate file?

so this is the code for the data being sent from the FRDM k64F via the XBee to Raspberry Pi

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "C12832.h" //for LCD
#include "FXOS8700Q.h"// for magnetometer

DigitalOut gpo(D0);
DigitalOut led(LED_RED);
Serial xbee(D1, D0);
C12832 shld_lcd (D11, D13, D12, D7, D10);
FXOS8700Q_mag mSensor(PTE25, PTE24, FXOS8700CQ_SLAVE_ADDR1);
MotionSensorDataUnits mData;

void setup() {
    xbee.baud(9600);
    }

    int main()
    {
        mSensor.enable();
        setup();
        while (1) {

            wait(5);
            mSensor.getAxis(mData);
                float mX = mData.x;
                float mY = mData.y;
                float mZ = mData.z;
                float mXYZ = (mX + mY + mZ)/3;
                shld_lcd.locate (1, 1);
                shld_lcd.printf("Magnetometer: %.2f \r \n", mXYZ);
                xbee.printf("Magnetometer: %.2f \r \n", mXYZ);
        }
    }
```

and the Raspberry Pi is able to read the data via the following command

```
screen/dev/ttyAMMAO 9600
```

Comment: We need to see your code. Without it, all we can suggest is `date >> timestamp_file`

Comment: @jDo please see the updated code above

Comment: Thanks for posting the code. That's arduino-C code though - I was expecting some shell script that opens a serial connection and parses the received data. You don't have any "receiver" code for the Raspi?

Comment: If you're starting from scratch on the receiving side, I recommend using Python rather than shell for parsing the incoming data. Sure, you could use a shell script that calls screen, minicom, picocom or whatever, but I think Python is just simpler to work with. There are lots of examples online; e.g. [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15600/reading-from-serial-port-loop), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21866762/sending-serial-communication-from-raspberry-pi) and among [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+serial+arduino+raspberry+pi)